# Return TextField makes BING in AWT

Tags: java, awt

Why does a return inside a TextField in Java AWT make a bing sound in dialogs? I have an old AWT program here, and run it under Java 7. It does not seem to matter, if the TextField has an action listener or not.

Update: I tried to isolate the problem writing another application with a dialog, but there is no beep. I also noticed that cursor up and down work in one program and in the other they cause a bing. However, there is no obvious code which is called to handle keystrokes.

Update: I also discovered that the right mouse button does not work in the beeping application.

Thanks for answers and help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` to indicate you pressed return when no text is present or for other validation reasons?

This may be invoked via the look-and-feel.  Is this application loading some custom look-and-feel?  If so, try disabling it and see if the behavior goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem: It is Java 7. Everything works fine in Java 6. So this is the work of Oracle, and probably there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  The issue is most likely an old, outdated look-and-feel.

Comment: No. It is a pure AWT program. So no look and feel.

Comment: I switched to Swing for many elements in the GUI. This removed the problem.